# Get name and version of available packages to text file - name and version only on same line, per package

Tags: command-line, apt

I am looking to get a text file with a list of some available packages and their latest version. I need to have the package name and its latest version on the same line.

**ATTEMPT**

Currently, I can get a version number for a single package:

example 1:

```
apt-cache show python-numpy | grep Version
```

This gives me 1 line of output:

```
Version: 1:1.8.2-2
```

example 2:

```
apt-cache show mysql-server | grep Version
```

This gives me 1 line of output:

```
Version: 5.5.44-0+deb8ul
```

**PROBLEM**:

There is more than one package that I am interested in.

**REQUIREMENT**

What I am looking for is the package name and the version - I would want this format:

```
python-numpy 1.8.2-2
mysql-server 5.5.44-0
python-six 1.8.0-1
python-wheel 0.24.0-1
apache2 2.4.10-10
python-urllib3 1.9.1-3
python-setuptools 5.5.1-1
```

If possible, I would like these 6 lines to be written to 'Output.txt'.
If it is not possible to get all these lines in the same file, then I would like to only get the 1st line above - `python-numpy 1.8.2-2` - in the output file.

**Question:**

Currently, I can get the name and version of each of these packages individually. However, is there a way to automate this process and get all at once?

EDIT:

The only packages I am looking for are:

```
python-wheel
python-numpy
mysql-server
python-setuptools
python-six
apache2
python-urllib3
```

Comment: What is "some available packages"?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I added the list to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the STDIN / STDOUT redirections: `done < input > Output.txt`.

Comment: I rolled back your question to the previous version since it doesn't really make sense to edit for a copy-paste error, the fix is just copying muru's script exactly as it's written.

Comment: The `apt-show-versions` command seems to come close to what you want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a list of packages (say, in a file named `input`, one per line), then you can do:

```sh
while read package
do
    echo $package "$(apt-cache show $package | awk '/Version/{print $2}')"
done < input > Output.txt
```

Comment: I have 2 questions: a. Is the above run from the terminal, or from a separate script? b. So, input.txt would like `python-wheel` `apache2` etc. etc....each on a new line?

Comment: @WR a. you can do it either way b. `input` would have `python-wheel` on one line, `mysql-server` on the next, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this both from a bash script file and directly from the terminal but I am getting an error message. I added this to the original post (Attempt 2) - all the error messages and output is there. Any thoughts about what might be causing this?

Comment: @WR Have a closer look at my code. You'll notice you're missing a `<` and a `>`.

Comment: Sorry, just want to clarify: Did you mean `< input.txt >`? Also, the `echo` line - should that be indented if I'm putting this in a  *.txt file?

Comment: It is `< input.txt`  and `> Output.txt`. You can indent as you wish, this isn't Python.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected that mistake and this is working now. One final question: between the package name and version, there is a space. Is it possible to replace the space by `->`?

Comment: @WR use `echo "$package->$(apt-cache show $package | awk '/Version/{print $2}')"`

Comment: Many thanks! Great answer - I have accepted it. It is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

After some wrangling with the `aptitude` documentation, including this Debian [aptitude search term reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html), I managed to come up with this ugly one-liner

```
aptitude -F '%p %V' --group-by=none --sort=name,~version versions \
  ?exact-name\({python-numpy,mysql-server,python-six,python-wheel,apache2,python-urllib3,python-setuptools}\) \
  | sort -uk1,1
```

- `-F '%p %V'` formats the output as *package name* and then *candidate version*
- `--sort=name,~version` sorts by package name and version *descending* so that we can use `sort -u` to skim off the newest
- `?exact-name()` prevents the search from being expanded to include things like `mysql-server-5.5` for `mysql-server`

Note the ugly brace expansion for the list of packages to check: there doesn't seem to be an option like `-oAptitude::Some::Param=true` to enforce `?exact-name()` globally.

---

FWIW the `apt-show-versions` utility seems to get 90% of the way there with 10% of the effort: here are the results for the packages you mention on my 14.04.3 system:

```
$ aptitude -F '%p %V' --group-by=none --sort=name,~version versions \
  ?exact-name\({python-numpy,mysql-server,python-six,python-wheel,apache2,python-urllib3,python-setuptools}\) \
  | sort -uk1,1
apache2 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8                                                        
mysql-server 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2                                            
python-numpy 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1                                                 
python-setuptools 3.3-1ubuntu2                                                  
python-six 1.5.2-1ubuntu1                                                       
python-urllib3 1.7.1-1ubuntu4                                                   
python-wheel 0.24.0-1~ubuntu1
```

whereas

```
$ apt-show-versions python-numpy mysql-server python-six python-wheel apache2 python-urllib3 python-setuptools
apache2 not installed
mysql-server:all/trusty-security 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 uptodate
python-numpy:amd64/trusty-updates 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1 uptodate
python-setuptools:all/trusty-updates 3.3-1ubuntu2 uptodate
python-six:all/trusty-updates 1.5.2-1ubuntu1 uptodate
python-urllib3:all/trusty-updates 1.7.1-1ubuntu4 uptodate
python-wheel:all/trusty-updates 0.24.0-1~ubuntu1 uptodate
```

The most obvious difference is it apparently doesn't include packages that are not currently installed.

Comment: Thank you! My main concern is that it works. The `aptitude` approach would be the better option here then. Why do you have `sort -uk1,1` rather than just `sort-u`?

Comment: @WR the `k1,1` is so that `sort` only looks at the first field (i.e. the package name) when eliminating duplicates. At least I *think* that's how it works.

Comment: You could use `?or()` instead of shell expansion, but that tends to make aptitude slow, so using regexes is prefered.

Comment: @Braiam thanks - do you know what the syntax of an `?or()` version would be? I tried that but couldn't seem to get it right

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchOr

Comment: @Braiam yeah I've read the documentation, apparently I just don't get it : when I try nesting a `?or()` inside the `?exact-name()` I get `E: Expected ')', got '('.` When I try the `|` form I get `E: Expected ')', got '|'.`

Comment: `?or(?exact-name(),?exact-name())`?

Comment: steeldriver, thanks regarding the `sort()` question!